# How to Export to Kml file from map android

Tags: android, export, kml

I have some trouble with map android. My map has some marker with title is text, and some `polyline`. Please take a look my picture .
[image]

Now, I want to export all item(marker with title, **polyline to kml** file to share with other device to display .I don't know how to do that.
 Please help me!

Comment: On a desktop browser go to Google MyMaps and export the KML file: https://support.google.com/mymaps/answer/3109452?hl=en

Comment: I wanna do in my client application? How to do that?

Comment: Its Google's product, all you can do is either export the KML or export a link to the KML. Rendering points and lines after that is up to you. This might help: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/kml#introduction

Comment: I could not find my answer...

Comment: @DươngNguyễnVăn if you find solution for this question, Please share it here.